# Could a spade bit be used to widen an existing hole in a wooden cabinet?

Tags: wood, woodworking, hole

The spade bit which I have is [this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00099E7WE).

Comment: Only if you have a way to keep it centered.  You can use a trick like sticking a wood plug in the old hole, then re-drilling.

Comment: How big is the current hole? How big do you want the enlarged hole to be?

Answer (score 5):

Use a hole saw with a long pilot drill bit and clamp a board to the other side of the existing board. The long pilot drill will ensure that the saw stays centered all the way through the board that you are cutting. There is usually no way to control the spade bit to keep it centered and cut a clean hole.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uGQSvkc4Ujw

Watch this video it shows a simple way to accomplish what you are trying to do.